# Giving mulitple Jbuttons the same actionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I have written a 2x2x2 rubiks cube solver and I want to make the experience for the user entering their cube better, currently they enter numbers which are assigned to colors of the cube. For example 0 could represent white, 1 could represent yellow etc. I have been working on a GUI that is a 2d cube made of buttons that when they are clicked change loop over an array of colors. This is what I have so far but I can't get the actionListener to apply to all the buttons.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 700;

    //create a window
    window.setTitle("First Window");
    window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);


        allButtons();
}

private static void allButtons(){
    panel.setLayout(null);
    window.add(panel);


     final JButton button[]=new JButton[23];
        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            button[i] = new JButton();
        }

        panel.add(button[0]);
        button[0].setBounds(30, 30, 60, 60);
        final Color[] ColorArray = {Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE,Color.GREEN,Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW};

        button[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                final int stickerNum = 24;

                if(stickerNum <= 3){
                    for(Color i : ColorArray){
                    button[0].setBackground(i);
                    cube[Side][0] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the ActionListener instance to a variable and add that to JButtons in a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 700;

    //create a window
    window.setTitle("First Window");
    window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);

    allButtons();
}

private static void allButtons(){
    panel.setLayout(null);
    window.add(panel);

    final JButton button[]=new JButton[23];
    for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        button[i] = new JButton();
    }

    panel.add(button[0]);
    button[0].setBounds(30, 30, 60, 60);
    final Color[] ColorArray = {Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE,Color.GREEN,Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW};

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            final int stickerNum = 24;

            if(stickerNum <= 3){
                for(Color i : ColorArray){
                    button[0].setBackground(i);
                    cube[Side][0] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        button[i].addActionListener( actionListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks how about laying them out because the code could end up looking like how It used to be.  `sideLabel.setText("Hello Enter your cube");
  sideLabel.setLocation(170, 5);
  panel.add(sideLabel);
  sideLabel.setSize(200,14);
  
  //add the buttons and put them in the right place 
  panel.add(button0);
  button0.setBounds(165,30,60,60);
  panel.add(button1); 
  button1.setBounds(242, 30, 60, 60);
  panel.add(button2);
  button2.setBounds(165, 105, 60, 60);
  `

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an ButtonListener class like below which stores an index. Then you just add a new instance of the listener to every button.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 700;

    //create a window
    window.setTitle("First Window");
    window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);


    allButtons();
}

private static void allButtons() {
    panel.setLayout(null);
    window.add(panel);


    final JButton button[]=new JButton[23];
    for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        button[i] = new JButton();
    }

    panel.add(button[0]);
    button[0].setBounds(30, 30, 60, 60);
    final Color[] ColorArray = {Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE,Color.GREEN,Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW};

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        private int buttonIndex;

        public ButtonListener(int buttonIndex) {
            this.buttonIndex = buttonIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final int stickerNum = 24;

            if(stickerNum <= 3){
                for(Color i : ColorArray){
                button[buttonIndex].setBackground(i);
                cube[Side][0] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i].addActionListener(new ButtonListener(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: How about when I add them to the panel, Is there a way I can avoid doing something like this?  @Jhonny007   https://i.imgur.com/4OlQJCx.png

Comment: I don't know how that should look, but you just could use a GridLayout on your panel and throw the setBounds out of the window. Otherwise you need to find a formula on how to calculate each position from the index.
Can you post a picture of how it should look?

Comment: This is how it should look, they are all spaced out by 75 pixels from each other. @Jhonny007  https://i.imgur.com/Vile2FX.png

Comment: There probably is a better way, but you could add them in rows, but it is hard to discribe in a comment. Just make a method, that takes a startIndex, an endIndex, an offSet and an int for which row. like:
`private static final int SIZE = 60;  
private static final int SPACING = 75;  
void addButtons(int first, int last, int offset, int row) {
    for(int i = first; i < last; i++) {
        panel.add(button[i]);
        button.setBounds(SIZE + SPACING * offset, SIZE + SPACING * row, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
}`